# How to associate a digit with each letter?

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I want to set a number for each alphabetic character. I normally get what I want when I do this

```
#!/bin/bash
A=4
B=6
c=5 
echo $A$A$B$c
```

but I need an easier way than putting `$` before each letter.

Comment: Can you share few more lines of code to help us understand if you just want ONLY these alphabet's $A$A$B$C values to be printed or it the echo statement changes everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option would be to use an **associative array**. That is of course if you don't have portability problems and are using bash version 4 and up.
You can do it like  this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

declare -A map
map[A]=4
map[B]=6
map[C]=5

STR="ABC"

echo -n "${STR}" | while IFS= read -r -n1 char; do
    echo -n ${map[${char}]}
done
echo
```

---

If you prefer creating a variable for each letter, like shown in your example, you can use the `eval` command:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

A=4
B=6
C=5

STR="ABC"

echo -n "${STR}" | while IFS= read -r -n1 char; do
    eval "echo -n \$${char}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `tr` to apply the translation map. For the case in your example:

```
echo AABc | tr ABc 465
```

This won't work if you are trying to use 2 digit numbers (eg, if you are trying to replace the entire alphabet with 0-25 or 1-26), but it's not at all clear what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Say if I have to do the aliter. Map words to numbers. Which is, a->1, b->2 ... and so on. Why doesnt ``echo hello | tr '[a-z]' '[1-26]' `` work? can you please elaborate?

Comment: tr translates single characters.  The character class `1-26` is identical to the set `126`, and using `[` doesn't work the way you might expect.  `tr '[a-z]'  '[1-26]'` is the same as `tr [abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz] [126]` which changes `[` to `[`, `a` to `1`, `b` to `2`, `c` to `6`, and `d` to `]`.  Also, since the first set is larger than the second, all other listed characters get converted to `]`.  It's just not designed to handle multi-character symbols.